# I am getting this error when build release in iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I am getting this error when building/archiving this project in Xcode. (Flutter)

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleAPIClientForREST'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_ml_vision'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_native_image'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/image_picker'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gurleensethi/FlutterProjects/camera_ml/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/path_provider'
ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar issues, and for me the problem was caused by opening Runner.xcodeproj instead of Runner.xcodeworkspace in XCode. This might seem obvious for people experience with XCode, but maybe this will help someone sometime.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have missing library try :

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter build ios`

Comment: Done it several times, no success!

Comment: i think this say that the build folder not found try run `flutter build ios` then try run using xcode

Comment: Its something regarding firebase, but I am not able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to fix a similar bug on library not found. Ultimately this is how I was able to resolve it

1. Before starting with Xcode Archive, used flutter build iOS
2. Changed the IOS Deployment Target to a higher target iOS 11.2 . Earlier I had something like 8.0 which was giving all the above errors.
3. Made sure that the IOS deployment targets in Xcode are same in the Project, Target and Pods